# How to post static web page with google apps engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Sorry, but I can't solve this issue by myself.. For example, I have a static web page and want to post it to the internet with own domain name like 'http://myowndomain.ru'. What steps I have to do for that? I already download Python and SDK. What next?

Comment: how about reading the docs, might be a good start https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles

Comment: What have you tried to do so far to solve the issue yourself? Including that in your post will give us a place to start, rather than just assuming you never bothered reading the docs. Use this [edit] link to add more details to your post. Good luck, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Gwyn, from where I must take app.yaml file?

Comment: jmort253, I already did 1-5 steps like the answer below (from Jonathan Newmuis), but I use this source: http://www.labnol.org/internet/host-website-on-google-app-engine/18801/
And that not help. So, I decided to search here for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a new web application project in your IDE
2. Place your static content in the `war/` directory of your application.
3. Create a new application on [appengine.google.com](http://appengine.google.com)
4. Set the application ID in app.yaml
5. Deploy your application to your App Engine app.
6. [Register your domain with Google Apps](https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/standard/new3).
7. Under "Application Settings" page of the admin console, select "Add Domain"
8. Type the name of your domain (e.g. mydomain.ru) in the box.
9. Follow the on-screen steps to complete this process.
10. Wait while DNS propagates...
11. You should now be able to access your static content.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where I can take  app.yaml file?